# setText Android was stopped

Tags: android

Why am I getting an error in `setText()`?.
If I remove it from the apllication it works fine, I also tried `append()`.

The xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.problema1multi.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botones"
            android:onClick="misteri"
            android:text="Misteri"
            android:width="500dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botones"
            android:onClick="risa"
            android:text="Risa"
            android:width="500dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botones"
            android:onClick="guerra"
            android:text="Guerra"
            android:width="500dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button boton1;
private Button boton2;
private Button boton3;
private TextView mensaje;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    boton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    boton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    boton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    mensaje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

}


public void detener(View v) {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
    }
}

public void risa(View arg0) {
    detener(arg0);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.risas);
    mp.start();
    mensaje.setText("Reproduciendo Risa");

}
```

Thanks!.

Comment: You definitely have a TextView with id `textView1` in your XML?

Comment: Without a logcat and XML it's hard to tell, but I'm guessing `mensaje` is null.

Comment: I have in my XML textView1.

Comment: Can you post the logcat then so we can see what exactly the error is?

Comment: post your `activity_main.xml` layout.

Comment: well , I can´t add more code to my first post .but probably I see the problem I need same kind of confirmation. I have the textView1 out of the linearlayout .

Comment: That shouldn't cause an error that is fixed by removing the "setText" line... I would try a clean and rebuild of the project if you haven't already.

Comment: Wait, this is your fragment XML `PlaceholderFragment` but you have posted your activity code?

Comment: Removing the line settext it works ,but i want it with the "setText".

Comment: The xml you posted is `activity_main.xml` right?

Comment: Actually the xml is fragment_main.xml .on the Activity_main.xml I have nothing .I don´t know what the difference between them.

Comment: You should read up on fragments vs activities. You have put your xml in fragment xml and you are referring to it in your activity, but your activity xml does not contain this textview at all, this is causing a NullPointerException.

Comment: Ok. i will pass all th items from fragment_main.xml to ativity_main.xml .Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You have posted your fragment xml but you are attempting to reference these views from your activity. The code you posted does not match the XML you posted at all. The code you posted references `activity_main.xml`

There is no TextView with id `textView1` in `activity_main.xml` so this is causing a `NullPointerException` when you try and call `setText` on it.

I would suggest you read up again on Fragments vs Activities - if this is a simple app you may not even need a Fragment at all and can just do everything within an activity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Java code you posted is your `Activity` code but the XML is your `Fragment` XML. I think you used the IDE Wizard to generate an Activity with Fragment so this changes a little from a simple Activity.

**Option 1:**

Move `mensaje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` into your `Fragment` `onCreateView()` method after inflating the XML layout, example:

```
TextView mensaje;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
   mensaje = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}
```

**Option 2:**

Use the `XML` you posted in your `Activity`, for example, if the XML is `main.xml`, in your `Activity` you have to use `setContentView(R.id.main);`

You should read more about [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html%20%22%22) to understand how they work. Also remember that in your `Activity` using `findViewById()` only returns refrences of the XML you inflated with `setContentView()` so your id `textView1` must be in your `activity_main.xml` layout.